# Add firebase to Android App using Smartface App Studio

Tags: android, firebase, smartface.io

I need to add Firebase to my App which I am developing using Smartface App Studio though I don't really know what the package name of my app is?
I tried just putting 'Smartface Demo' however it didn't work.

Where it asks for the package name:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The package name is a unique identifier that every app has. Usually, it's something like "com.company_name.app_name" (without quotes)

The debug package name (the one that you can use with the free smartface version) is "io.smartface.SmartfaceDemo" (again, without quotes), to change that, you have to go to your profile's Desktop Panel and add a package there (only if you have a paid version).
So, if you are using a free license, use io.smartface.SmartfaceDemo

Obs: Firebase doesn't have a library for Smartface, you have to use Firebase's REST API. 
Here's a link to Firebase's REST API documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-api-usage